# Accepting criticism

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrases, expressions

What are some words or phrases that say that we will accept criticism or any words thrown at us? 
I want to respond in a way so the bond between us is never broken. I don't want to take things seriously. I want to say something along the lines of "you are a beloved person and you can say or do whatever you want. I don't care."

Comment: "Love means never having to say you're sorry" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_means_never_having_to_say_you%27re_sorry

Comment: The sentiments in your sample sentence are excellent. Unfortunately, this site isn't suited to open-ended questions. If you'd like to redraft to focus your question in a manner more readily answerable, see [Notes to Reviewers](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7913/142322).

Answer (score 2):

You could tell the person to [**pull no punches**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+no+punches)

> to deal with something honestly without hiding anything

Or you could tell them there are [**no holds barred**](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/no-holds-barred.html)

> Without restrictions or rules.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're **open to** criticism, new ideas or suggestions.

### [Open to](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/open+to)

**open to something**

> agreeable to hear or learn about new ideas and suggestions.
>
> *"The store owner was open to suggestions from her employees."*
>
> *"We are always open to new ideas."*